# Numba with complex arrays

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, numba

I am testing numba to optimize some code and have ran into some confusing behavior.  Namely, I am getting the error:

```
TypingError: Internal error at numba.typeinfer.IntrinsicCallConstraint object at 0x1180abc50:

"Don't know how to create implicit output array "
NotImplementedError: Don't know how to create implicit output array with 'A' layout.
```

Here is the test code:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit , complex64, float32,float64,complex128


x = np.linspace(0,100,100);
y = np.linspace(0,100,100);

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
mesh = np.asarray([X,Y])

@jit(complex128[:,:](float64[:,:,:],float64),nopython = True)
def test2(mesh,qq):    
    I = np.complex(0,1)
    q = mesh[0]+I*mesh[0]
    return q
```

It should output a complex version of mesh.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you using `nopython=True`, and at the same time invoking `np.complex`.  I thought `np` was a Python module?

Comment: A lot of the numpy api is supported in `nopython` mode including `np.complex`: http://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/0.26.0/reference/numpysupported.html. Actually the code runs fine for me using Numba 0.26 without raising an error. I can't attest to whether the output matches the OP's expectations.

Comment: I'm not getting any output just the above error, I was running Numba 0.21, I will upgrade and see if anything has changed.

Comment: Have you upgraded? Has it changed?